# PhpStorm code style and PHP_CodeSniffer conflict: Multi-line function call not indented correctly; expected 12 spaces but found 16

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpcodesniffer, psr-12

I am using PHP_CodeSniffer like this to scan my code:

```sh
vendor/bin/phpcs --standard=PSR12 src
```

I also configured PhpStorm to use PSR-12 at `Preferences -> Editor -> Code Style -> Set From -> PSR12`

When I run PHP_CodeSniffer there are no error at first, but if U auto indent with PhpStorm my file and re run PHP_CodeSniffer I get some errors:

```
 286 | ERROR | [x] Multi-line function call not indented correctly; expected 12 spaces but found 16
 287 | ERROR | [x] Multi-line function call not indented correctly; expected 12 spaces but found 16
 288 | ERROR | [x] Multi-line function call not indented correctly; expected 12 spaces but found 16
```

I tried to change the configuration of tabs and indents, by default it's this:

[image]

I've not found any configuration that works, and I don't understand what could be the problem since I use PSR12 in both PhpStorm and PHP_CodeSniffer.

I also have this phpcs.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ruleset xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" name="PHP_CodeSniffer"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="phpcs.xsd">
    <description>The coding standard for PHP_CodeSniffer itself.</description>

    <file>src</file>

    <arg name="basepath" value="."/>
    <arg name="colors"/>
    <arg name="parallel" value="8"/>
    <arg value="p"/>
    <arg value="s"/>

    <!-- Don't hide tokenizer exceptions -->
    <rule ref="Internal.Tokenizer.Exception">
        <type>error</type>
    </rule>

    <rule ref="PSR12"></rule>
    <rule ref="PSR2"></rule>
    <rule ref="PSR1"></rule>

</ruleset>
```

Comment: ı reccomend this to you. https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer

Comment: Do mean instead of `PHP_CodeSniffer`or to auto fix the code instead of using phpstorm ?

Comment: no ı am using  that command

Comment: We need to see a full code block where the problem is happening. It is most likely caused by an incorrect PhpStorm PSR 12 code style configuration. It is best to report this at PhpStorm tracker directly at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue for a corresponding team to check & address.